# Is there any type of development platforms for systems which have both electronic and mechanical components together with software components?

Tags: agile, project-management, development-process

I am starting to work in a company. In this company, we have a set of products. These products are inherently related and have many shared functionalities and parts. Each of our products consists of a number of components. Types of these components are small software code, electronic boards, and mechanical pieces.

After nearly fifteen years of developing and deploying these products to many customers, the managers of this company feel being frustrated with management, updating, improving, and developing new related products.

Another important problem is that after these years, they understood that we have to develop our products based on software and not hardware, as they have already been doing. Currently, our products are based on electronic and mechanical components and software is mainly to control hardware devices. Now we have to develop products that are able to provide more information and features to the user in mobile apps and store data regarding our devices in servers. In other words, we change the mindset from developing hardware devices with small software codes to software products which control related hardware devices.

Nearly all of the employees are not computer engineering professionals. They have a bachelor's or master's degrees in electronics, control or mechanical engineering. My questions are:

1- Does anyone have such an experience to set up such a development system for such a workforce?

2- Is there any type of development platforms that considers version control and artifact management for electronic and mechanical components together with the software process management? Are ordinary software development platforms are good for these types of products?

3- Meanwhile as a very small step toward this goal, they are looking for a tool that enables them to manage documents produced in developing these products and linking them to other documents in the system. It is very good if this tool has version control and change management together with access control. Can I suggest using change management and version control software such as Rational ClearCase or git?

In summary:

Is there any type of development platforms for systems that have both electronic and mechanical components together with software components?

Comment: see [Where to start?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/31260)

Comment: @gnat, Please note that we have a specific problem which is we have software and hardware components. How to change the question ?

Comment: software recommendations are off-topic here, sorry. See [help/on-topic]

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I am an experienced math.SE user. Is there any type of these systems that can address my problem?

Comment: Having hardware and software components together is not a specific problem; it is a means to solve a specific problem.  There are many such platforms.  Sometimes all you need is a library that talks to the hardware and an off-the-shelf IDE.

Comment: However, I'll play the home game.  Have a look at Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Thank you for your response. Please note that our problem is developing and management of various versions of these systems. Many of our devices have been developed in our company. Not about Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: Can you tease out for me the *specific problem* you're trying to solve?  Have you already articulated it in your question?

Comment: In other words: are the development of a set of hybrid software-hardware systems are inherently different from development of a set of pure software systems? If it is not, then we can forget the hardware and use one of the software development platforms?

Comment: No, it's not different.  The computer that you're typing on is a hardware/software system.

Comment: But they don't develop such a system by these platforms, do they?

Comment: You mean a "hybrid system?"   Everything connected to your computer, your mouse, your keyboard, your webcam, is a  "hybrid system."  (for some definition of "hybrid").

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104056/discussion-between-robert-harvey-and-user85361).

Comment: Yes, I mean a hybrid system. Our products are such systems

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robot_software

Comment: I think you are asking this question in the wrong place.  The Qs and As here seem to be overwhelmingly about software and software engineering, whereas your question is about ... well it's about a transition that 1,001 companies and industries have made or are making right now.  Think of the automotive industry which has gone from being almost entirely mechanical- and electronic-engineering 20 years ago to one where now software is at least as important as hardware.  I suspect https://engineering.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this, but do check their Ts and Cs.

Comment: Alright.  I read your question again, and it seems as if what you really need are *software developers,* as your engineers don't possess the requisite skills to build large software systems.  So hire some software developers.  Software developers write software.  Your task is to teach them your hardware, so that they can write software for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharing my personal answer for getting started. It won't answer all of your question. It is too broad for a post.

Even combining with hardware, it is still a kind of version control. Electronical design is rotaing slower than software I'd suggest don't take the combination as a "version".

Taking care of each control software and firmware version independantly would reduce the "version" numbers  you need to take care of.

Using your product revision to record combination.

Eg: Product A rev1.2 using control software  s1.2, firmware f3.4, GUI g5.6 with hardware H revision 7.8.

Actual combination would be more complex than my example.

Meanwhile you need some knowledge sharing tools for infegrating version control system. Stackoverflow itselt has an [enterprise solution](https://stackoverflow.com/enterprise). You may start from consulting them.